# Insert into function with multiple dynamic input elements

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

I am currently trying to create some dynamic contents in between two different tables from my database.

First, "table1" will include the values. This table may expand dynamically.

These entries creating a dynamic form as creating dynamic input tags as much as found in table1.

What i excatly want to make is, i would like to pass those dynamic entries in table2 as well whenever i submit the form.

Here is the full example of this project. Even creating tables and sample entries.

Basically i do not know what to put instead "???" in "insert_into_table2" function.

Thanks a lot from now.

```
<?php
check_tables();
insert_tables();
if(isset($_GET['new']) && isset($_GET['new']) == ''){
    $somevalue = 'Some Value';
    insert_into_table2($somevalue);
}
function check_tables(){
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test");
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
            `table1_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `table1_no` int(3) NOT NULL,
            `table1_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `table1_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`table1_ID`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {}
    $connection->close();
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test");
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
            `table2_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `table2_row1` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
            `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
            `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
            PRIMARY KEY (`table2_ID`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {}
    $connection->close();
}
function insert_tables(){
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`table1_ID`, `table1_no`, `table1_title`, `table1_description`) VALUES
                (1, 1, 'Name', 'name'),
                (2, 2, 'Lastname', 'lastname');";
        if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {}
        $connection->close();
    }
}
function insert_into_table2($somevalue){
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table2` (`table2_row1`, '???') VALUES ('$somevalue', '???');";
    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {}
    $connection->close();
}
?>
<form method="post" action="?new" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY table1_no ASC";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<input type="text" name="name[]" value="" placeholder="'.$row['table1_title'].'"/><br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I am sorry that i have had to make some changes in codes as i noticed that i was missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days with no help from other people. I figured it out and just wanted to share in here if someone else is interested in.

First of all, i have assigned a name to submit button to make trigger work.
Instead of this;

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

I used this;

```
<input type="submit" name="new_entry"/>
```

Then of course, change the trigger as well. From;

```
isset($_GET['new']) && isset($_GET['new']) == ''
```

To;

```
isset($_POST['new_entry'])
```

Finally i was able to get the values from columns and inputs and added code under;

```
function insert_into_table2($somevalue){
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "testuser", "testpass", "test");
```

The code is;

```
$sqlfc = "SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY table1_no ASC";
    $result = $connection->query($sqlfc);
    $columns_ = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $values = implode("', '", $_POST["name"]);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $columns_[] = $row['table1_description'];
        }
        $columns = implode(", ",$columns_);
    }
```

For the final i was able to change question marked areas. Such as from;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table2` (`table2_row1`, '???') VALUES ('$somevalue', '???');";
```

To;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (table2_row1, $columns) VALUES ('$somevalue', '$values');";
```

It's all working now. I thought i could get help from here but i was not that lucky this time. Hope this may help someone else at least.